# On the same button when tap first time change the size of text,when tap second time changes to default

Tags: android, flutter, dart, frontend, flutter-test

trying to change the text size in textfield dynamically using a single button. already used setstate but it changes only single time. do not know how to change it again on second tap

Comment: Is default something global, like let's say the default value for every text view is 12sp? Or default for that particular textview, so each textview has its own default size different from others?

Comment: maintain a boolean value then on click check the boolean and repeat your code with different text size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**and use this  you can change the font size of textfield**

```
  double fSize=16;
       TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: fSize),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Custom Text',

            ),
          ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {setState(() {
                fSize = fSize == 16 ? 32: 16;
              });},
              child: Text("change size"),
            ),
```

**for full example**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PrivacyPolicyState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {

  double fSize=16;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 16, 24, 0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
          TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: fSize),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Custom Text',

            ),
          ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {setState(() {
                fSize = fSize == 16 ? 32: 16;
              });},
              child: Text("change size"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```